# Display Content after override a template

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, wpf-controls

I have this content to be displayed:

Scene:
[image: Scene]

Code:
[image: Code]

But i don't know how to display this in a overrided template. I've putted the template to the card, but the result is this:

Scene:
[image: Scene]

Code:
[image: Code]

What can i do for solve that?

Comment: Give the `materialDesign.Card` element the attribute `Template="{StaticResource MaterialCard}"`

Comment: Better yet, create a default `Style` for `materialDesign.Card` that has a `Setter` for the `Template` property that uses that template.

Comment: FYI: For future reference, code should be posted as text (code-formatted), not as images.

Comment: Tysm! Also, thanks for notify me about the images, i won't make the same mistake again ;).